# Rename package name in android

Tags: java, android, package, android-manifest

I want to rename package name in my project. I have 9 packages so far and when I have change package name ,the changes are done in java and xml file.

But in Manifest.xml file, the activity definition section , package activity doesn't change after  rename package.

Please help me.

Comment: AFAIK you will have to manually change it in manifest file as there is no other option, if there is one i am also waiting for the same.

Comment: but in my manifest file,there are 20 activity.so how can you possible manually change all file package name?

Answer (score 3):

There is an option for this in Android Tools, here are the steps for doing this

1. Right Click on the project
2. Click on Android Tools
3. Click on Rename Application Project
4. Enter the new package name

Comment: but in this way,android manifest file not be changed.please give me other solution.

Comment: Have you checked the checkbox "update fully qualified names in non-java text files" while renaming the package?

Comment: yes. i already tried it. manifest file package name change but declared activity packagename not change.

Answer (score 1):

First change the package name in the manifest file
Re-factor > Rename the name of the package in src folder and put a tick for rename  subpackages, thats it.

Comment: ` <com.whatsupfeedback.customview.CustomEditText
            android:id="@+id/loginedtUserName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/usericn"
            CustomView:Hint="@string/username"/>`

do not change packagename in customeview added in xml file

Answer (score -2):

Could you use Search and replace?

In Eclipse:

Open the AndroidManifest.xml

Edit-->Find/Replace

Find: old.app.name
Replace With: new.app.name

Click OK.

Just check everything is OK before you save the file.

/Steffen

Comment: It is, if the xml file is the only place the change needs to be done. And that's how I understand your question.